# Kotlin SpringMVC - JpaRepository generating invalid update query

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I'm quite new to Spring MVC, and I'm having problems getting a simple entity update to work.

My data class looks like this...

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints=[UniqueConstraint(columnNames=["name_search"])])
data class ArticleType(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long? = null,
        val name : String = "",
        val order: Int? = null,
        var name_search : String = ""
)
```

The repository looks like so...

```
interface ArticleTypeRepository : JpaRepository<ArticleType, Long> {
    fun findFirstById(id: Long) : ArticleType?

    fun findAllByOrderByOrderAsc(): List<ArticleType>

    fun findByName(name: String): ArticleType?
}
```

I'm trying to update the name_search column like so...

```
val article_type:ArticleType? = articleTypeRepository.findFirstById(1234)
if (article_type !== null) {
    article_type.name_search = "abc"
    articleTypeRepository.save(article_type)
}
```

This results in the following error...

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order=99 where id=1234' at line 1

I'm assuming this means the binding isn't working correctly, and it's missing the "name_search" binding, or missing the quotes or something. I've turned on logging, and I can see the following...

org.hibernate.SQL : update article_type set name=?, name_search=?, order=? where id=?

Then it lists the binding parameters "o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder", which all appear to be correct.

I'm not sure what's going wrong, or where I need to start to try to fix it.

This is a legacy system I've inherited, and I don't fully understand it. If there is some extra information I need to provide here, please let me know.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Spring MVC. You're using a reserved SQL keyword as the name of your field/column: `order`. Don't. And please respect the Java/Kotlin naming conventions, too.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't know how to correctly label the question. It's a Spring application, but perhaps that wasn't relevant to my question. Given that "order" is the name of the column, how can I deal with this? As I mentioned I inherited this application, I didn't choose that column name. Is there some way to tell it to escape the column names in the query?

Comment: I don't know. I would do the right thing and choose a better name.

Comment: Potential workaround - rename your order variable e.g `precedence`, then annotate with `@Column(name="order")` to allow us to refer to the column by a different name, your query would then need to be updated to: `findAllByOrderByPrecendenceAsc()`

Comment: Thanks @EamonScullion. Would this help though, as it's the column name, not the variable name that's causing problems I.e. It's erroring only when it tries to run the query against MySQL.

Comment: Should allow you to  use the variable name, to work out what column name to use (specified in the @Column annotation)

Comment: I've found what seems to be a fairly simple work-around...
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
With this set to true, it wraps all the column names in backticks, and the error goes away.